# Implementing Seguey changes the size of the Safe Area in Swift

Tags: swift, segue

When I segue from one view controller to another, the size of the Safe Area of the destination controller shrink(refer to an image - circled) resulting in a grey patch. I have googled on this issue but don't seem to find a solution. Hope someone could help. Tks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your UINavigation controller change the Presentation to Full Screen it will solve your issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*I can't comment*

I've tried the segue and it didn't cause the problem like [Your attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi1cZ.jpg).

Have you tried restarting your XCode?

My segue: [Attachment](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YUgTGApukVAE8h08JN_Y0AVd9X6XUIJC)